# Discrepancy between calculation and simulation

Tags: resistors, switched-capacitor

I am trying to implement resistors with switched-capacitors (SC). Consider the circuit below.

[image]

SC can simulate a resistor by repeatedly charging and discharging a capacitor. Clocks clk1 and clk2 have the same frequency, except that they don't overlap so that when clk1 is HIGH, the capacitor is charging, and when clk2 is HIGH, the capacitor is discharging.

I am trying to create a voltage weighting circuit. Assuming I'm using resistors instead of SC resistors, the voltage at the output is equal to:

$$V_{out} = \frac{V_1 \cdot \frac{1}{R_1} + V_2 \cdot \frac{1}{R_2}}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}}$$

Now, if I replace by resistors with SC implementation, the \$V_{out}\$ I expect is given below.

Using KCL at the output node:

$$I_1 + I_2 = 0$$
$$\frac{(V_1 - V_{out})C_1}{\Delta t_1} + \frac{(V_2 - V_{out})C_2}{\Delta t_2} = 0$$

where \$\Delta t_1\$ is the period of the clk1 and clk2.

Let's assume \$\Delta t_1\$ = \$2 \Delta t_2\$ and \$C_1 = C_2\$ to make things easier. We get:

$$V_{out} = \frac{\frac{V_1}{2} + V_2}{\frac{3}{2}}$$

If I plug in \$V_1=5\$ and \$V_2=2\$, then I should get \$V_{out}=3\$. I ran the simulation and got an average \$V_{out}=3.5\$. Simulating with other input voltage values, there's a 0.5V that I am not accounting for. What I am missing ?

Comment: How did you arive at Vout=3V ?

Comment: Using the equation for Vout.

Comment: Background of my question:  I arrive at 3.5V (using the first equation at the top of your text).  Try to recalculate.